# Creating line chart from json data

Tags: php, json

I have JSON data in this format:

```
{"total_in_room":"0","change_from_last":"-2","capacity":"20","unixtimedate":"1457330109"}`
{"total_in_room":"0","change_from_last":"-2","capacity":"20","unixtimedate":"1457330109"}`
```

What I want to do is that I want to create a simple line plot on which the x-axis has unixtimedate values and y-axis has total_in_room values. I was trying to convert this into JS but failed to do that. However, I can put all x-axis values in one array and y-values in another in another array in json. But I don't to know what to do from there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I've never found two charting libraries that expect the same format. Which one are you using?

Comment: are you using high chart js ?

Comment: I tried using js but wasn't sure what to do really.. I have no idea what to do as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a jquery chart plugin. Here is some of them:

[1.Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/)

[2.Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/)

[3.jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/)

And also You can use [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/11-best-jquery-charting-libraries/)  to learn some jquery chart plugins.